# GraphQL: Problem with case convertion in queries/mutations

Tags: javascript, postgresql, knex.js, graphql-js

I am using Postgres for my database, Knex to build the database, Graphql to run queries and mutations and Vue.js in front-end.

The problem is, i need to show the values from the table(s) in the front-end, but i am having problems with case conversion, my DB uses snake_case, but the API uses camelCase.

```
cotacoesLoad: async (_root, _args, ctx, _info) => {
    return ctx.database('cotacoes')
  },
```

i'm also using a field resolver to bring data from a related table:

```
cliente: async (root, _args, ctx, _info) => {
    return ctx.database('erp_clientes').where({ id: root.cliente_id }).first()
  }
```

this is how I typed the table and the query in graphql:

```
type Cotacao {
  id: String!
  cliente: ErpCliente!
  situacao: Int
  localEntrega: Int
  amostraInicial: String
  lotePiloto: String
  producao: String
  ferramental: String
  dataEnvio: LocalDate
  nrCotacaoCliente: Int
}

extend type Query {
  cotacoesLoad: [Cotacao!]!
}
```

the result of the query in playground:

```
{
  "data": {
    "cotacoesLoad": [
      {
        "cliente": {
          "nome": "mestre"
        },

        "situacao": 1,
        "localEntrega": null,
        "amostraInicial": null,
        "lotePiloto": null,
        "producao": "produ",
        "ferramental": "a",
        "dataEnvio": null,
        "nrCotacaoCliente": null
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

the issue is: fields that are represented with more than 1 word (example: localEntrega) are returning null, probally because there is no case convertion and the DB will only recognize single-word fields.

I can't use snake case in my API, so i ask, what would be the best way to convert those camelCased fields to snake_case fields?

i've tried to just write the fields in snake_case but I know this isn't the right way to do.

other thing i've done was a file to rename all these camelCased fields to snake_case in a 'fields' file like this:

```
localEntrega: root => {
    return root.local_entrega
  }
```

but it was not accepted because its also a bad way to do it.

Comment: What do you mean by "*it was not accepted*"?

Comment: Knex should support column aliases.

Comment: not accepted by my tutor

Comment: If you have a tutor, surely they know a better solution?

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. Don't add tags.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [knex-stringcase](https://www.npmjs.com/package/knex-stringcase) package to convert in both directions between camelCase and snake_case.

This allows you to have use proper camelCase types and fields in your model (and GraphQL) while interfacing with a case-insensitive database.